# datagrid view will not populate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I need some serious help here. I am doing a project for college which involves using a MS access database. The problem is my data-grid shows noting. No error no noting. I used a table.rows.count a used a message box to make sure there was data. It showed the correct number . Oh and another thing my form is docked within another form i don't know will this make any difference.

Any help would be appreciated .
Alex

```html
namespace Health_plus_MRS
{
    public partial class SearchDoctor : Form
    {
        public SearchDoctor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        
        public SearchDoctor(NavigationForm oForm): this()
        {
            this.navform = oForm;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public NavigationForm navform
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        private void returnToNavPB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            navform.Show();
            this.Close();
            this.Dispose();
        }




        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            searchAll();   
   

        }


        public void searchAll()
        {
            
            OleDbConnection conToDataBase = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Resources\health_plus.accdb;Persist Security Info=True");
            OleDbCommand searchAllCom = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Doctors", conToDataBase);

            conToDataBase.Open();

            searchAllCom.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OleDbDataAdapter searchDocAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(searchAllCom);
            DataTable doctorsTable = new DataTable();
           
            searchDocAdapter.Fill(doctorsTable);

            searchDoctorDataGrid.DataSource = doctorsTable;

        }

        private void SearchDoctor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried searchDoctorDataGrid.DataBound(); after this searchDoctorDataGrid.DataSource = doctorsTable?

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger, where does it fail?  Are any results returned from the SQL query?  Does the `DataTable` get populated with anything?

Comment: Try setting your grid.dataSource to null before populating it with your sql result. I had a similar issue once anyway. Your code looks good though I'd use try/catch

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the comments. @SelvaTS I tried that but it. but datbind cant be found it come underlined in red , I read online that DataBind method is not needed in winforms, just in webforms.

Comment: @David debugger is saying noting . There is no error. Noting at all happens, the data-grid view just staying empty . I really tried everything.  Its really killing me this far in

Comment: Okays guys i found the problem I opened the search doctor form on its own(Not being docked within the main form ) and it worked fine . Now i faced with another problem but a least I am getting somewhere lol.

Comment: @AlexKirwan: If the debugger doesn't do anything (that is, it doesn't let you step through the code or stop on any breakpoints) and literally *nothing* is happening then it sounds like the application isn't even running at all.  The code needs to actually execute in order to do anything...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to explicitly bind the data when setting the `DataSource` property of a `DataGrid`.

So what you need to add after setting the data source is:

```
searchDoctorDataGrid.DataBind();
```

From the documentation:

> Use the DataBind method to bind the data source specified by the DataSource property to the data listing control. By binding the data source to a data listing control, the information in the data source is displayed in a data listing control.

See also the [documentation on `DataBind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7c2tz18%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks very much for the help but DataBind i been underlined in red .